# Armature Python Animation

Tags: animation, blender

I want to animate a foot in blender with python. I have already made the foot and the armature and animated it by inserting key frames manually. But I need the animation to vary depending on some variables, this is why I need to animate it using pthon. How can I do this??

I've tried with the command "keyframe_insert" but it didn't designate a pose from the foot to the key frame.

```
import bpy

DOU = bpy.data.objects["Exoesqueleto"]

DOU.keyframe_insert(data_path = "rotation_axis_angle", frame=0)

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.29104, 0, 0),
  constraint_axis=(False, False, False), 
  constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', 
  mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', 
  proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
  proportional_size=1)

DOU.keyframe_insert(data_path = "rotation_axis_angle", frame=5)
```

I expect the foot to moove when I went through frames 0 to 5, but it just mooved in one direction that wasn't even the direction I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `keyframe_insert` on each pose bone, not the armature object.

```
import bpy

rig = bpy.data.objects['Exoesqueleto']
bone = rig.pose.bones['Bone']

bone.rotation_euler = (0, 0, 0)
bone.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame=1)

bone.rotation_euler = (0.29104, 0, 0)
bone.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame=5)
```

Also for blender specific scripting, you will find more help at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I tried your code (I put the number of the bone), it inserts the key frames but the foot doesn't moove. I tried writing onli bone.rotation_euler = (0.29104, 0, 0) and it didn't moove.

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case, using bone.rotation_quaternion instead (and then 'rotation_quaternion' in the keyframe_insert call) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Actually, whether the `rotation_euler` or `rotation_quaternion` properties are used would depend on the setting you have for [rotation mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/scene_layout/object/properties/transforms.html)